# eCommerce desktop dry-run issue

Tags: sql, database, nopcommerce, localserver

So the situation is that I've d/l nopCommerce and a slew of other web development programs in order to save some cash on my business.

I've created a local server/database with sql anywhere 12, and then run nopCommerce with VS2010 to begin the install, but receive this error message when attempting to connect with the server:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I've also ran the same db in VS and tried running it that way, while nopCommerce asks for a server name, I've tried many to no avail.

Checked spelling, I'm running everything local, so none of this makes sense.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying yes you can connect to the database with VS2010, and cannot with the other utility; or neither connection will work?  Also, is the target RDBMS "SQL Anywhere" or "SQL Server"?  You state SQL Anywhere, but your application appears to be trying SQL Server- is this the issue?

Comment: So in order to run nopCommerce locally, I needed to do none of that. Just enter the server as .\SQLEXPRESS and select windows auth. then continue.  The database is created in the next step of the installation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled Named Pipes protocol for your SQL server?

[image]